# mysql connects to localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql

Im in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

if I do `mysql -h localhost -u root` I can connect with no issues. But if I do, `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root` I get:

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the rest of the message?

Comment: Perhaps mysql is only listening on IPv6 - check what address localhost resolves to.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL considers `127.0.0.0/8` addresses to be different from `localhost` so when creating users if you specify one you need to connect using that one reference.

Additionally, some MySQL connectors will use a socket when connecting to `localhost` but use TCP/IP when connecting to `127.0.0.1`

Finally, one of the more recent differences is if `localhost` is used socket authentication is done - if you are logged in as the root user, you can be logged in to MySQL w/o a password.  Played silly buggers with some backup scripts I wanted to run via `cron` when I first found that one...